# Place view at bottom of ListView in program

Tags: android, listview, view

When i click an already existing element in my `ListView`, im changing its color, but i also want to place it at the bottom of the `ListView`
Is there a way to place a given `View` from a `ListView` to the bottom of the `ListView`?

Comment: Sure. What have you tried?

Comment: Abit clueless how to do it, tried to move all the other views to the top with `BringChildToFront`, which seems to be a realy bad way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about footer view this how it is implemented.

Your footer xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="7dip"
    android:paddingBottom="7dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView 
        android:text="@string/footer_text_1" 
        android:id="@+id/footer_1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="14dip" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your activity class

```
 public class MyListActivty extends ListActivity {
        private Context context = null;
        private ListView list = null;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            //code to set adapter to populate list
            View footerView =  ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
            list.addFooterView(footerView);
        }
```

Comment: I already got some elements in the listview, and when i click it i change its color, but i also want to put it into the bottom of the listview, but got no clue how :(

Comment: just rearrange the collection that you are using to fill the listview to put that elements at the end and call notifydatasetchange() method to reflect the changes.